# jquery wrap elements with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gurus,

I have this.

```
<td style="width:100px">
Queued:465
Rejects:3897
Offers:31
</td>
```

and need to make it as

```
<td style="width:100px">
<span class="label">Queued:</span><span class="data">465</span> <br>
<span class="label">Rejects:</span><span class="data">3897</span><br>
<span class="label">Offers:</span><span class="data">31</span>
</td>
```

Instead of one single line (Queued:465 Rejects:3897 Offers:31), I want to give a break after the numbers(they are dynamic). Queued, Rejects, Offers are fixed.

This is what I tried with.

```
$('td:contains(Queued:)').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('Queued:', '<span class="label">Queued: </span>');
});
$('td:contains(Rejects:)').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('Rejects:', '<br><span class="label">Rejects: </span>');
});
$('td:contains(Offers:)').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('Offers:', '<br><span class="label">Offers: </span>');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("td").html(function(i, val) {
    return $.trim(
        val.replace(/[a-z]+/ig, '<span class="label">$&</span>')
           .replace(/\d+/g, '<span class="data">$&</span>')
    ).replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dfRzY/

Answer (score 0):

You can also go down the .split route rather than the Regex route.

```
var $td = $("td"),
    rows = $td.html().trim().split("\n"),
    html = [];

for (var x=0; x<rows.length; x++){
  var line = rows[x].split(":");

  html.push(
    "<span class='label'>"+line[0]+":</span>"+
    "<span class='data'>"+line[1]+"</span>"
  );
}
$td.html(html.join("<br>"));
```

Edit: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VsAGL/)

Comment: There are more `newlines` than you think. Don't forget to `trim`!

Comment: Hi! VisioN and Dolondro,

Thank you very much. There might be a slight modification needed and might have to come back to you...;o(( Quick answer and works like a charm.

Comment: Hi! Dolondro, I spoke in haste. I am afraid the code you gave me is not working. I think I spoke in haste....Any chance you could try it in fiddle..please

Comment: Hi! VisionN, Your code works perfectly in simple table but when I take it over to the table that has lots of <<tr><td> eg<tr><td>Department</td></tr> then it messes up the text....

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I put the trim() in the wrong place. It should work now, jsfiddle to follow.

Comment: Dolondro, thank you very much. It works. But now we are looking at it from a slightly different angle.

As the question is bit long, I had to create a different post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350665/jquery-pass-value-into-string-and-make-it-an-anchor